# Index was out of range in Genexus

Tags: genexus

In Genexus I have a variable and I want to pass the value to an attribute. Activate the Business Component but I get the following error when in the button I put the event of the procedure.

The procedure code:

```
&Mercaderia.Precio = &Precio
&Mercaderia.Save()
```

[image]

Comment: Please, show us the types of &Mercaderia, Precio Attribute and &Precio variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you made the load previous to the Update (Save)?:

```
&Mercaderia.Load(<MercaderiaPK>)
&Mercaderia.Precio = &Precio
&Mercaderia.Save()
```